# Recover python script after blender crash

Tags: python, scripting

When writing a script and Blender crashes I lose the changes in my script? If blender crashes, I can only get the scripts I've saved manually saved (via <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> or *Edit > Save*).

Often I will do *Run Script* and I thought that also saves the script, but apparently it doesn't.

Is there a way to either recover, or does Blender save the last "run" script somewhere?

Comment: Assume you mean a script in blenders' text editor. Best bet is to `File > Recover > Auto save` .. which will depend on time between auto-save and crash.

Comment: On my last crash, I did this, but it did not recover the script in the text editor, only the blender file. Is it supposed to also recover the script? (If it did, it was long since autosave).

Comment: @remi at time of auto save, whatever is in the Text Editor gets saved as well. That is the only time you can get the script recovered. Otherwise impossible to recover so always make sure you save or back up your script before running.